# Get ONLY values that contain both a letter and a number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have few junk values in telephone column like this:

```
   tel
  -----
  ID# 12
  ID23
  45(ID)
  MYID
  YOUR ID
```

I wanted the result should be like this.

```
   tel
  -----
  ID# 12
  ID23
  45(ID)
```

I have written a query like this:

```
   PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%',TEL) = 0
```

However, I'm not getting the excepted result. Could any one has a clue? Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic behind your desired results?   You only want to return results that have numbers in them?

Comment: Yes, I wanted  (ID# 12
  ID23
  45(ID)). That is both numbers and alphabets only.

Comment: If you are looking for the junk values why is MYID and YOUR ID not returned? Those seem highly unlikely to be valid values for a phone number.

Comment: Note that any query that merely wants to know if something matches a pattern can use `LIKE`, rather than comparing the result of `PATINDEX` against 0. `PATINDEX` is only required if you want the position of the first match. I mention this because both your question and several answers use it in ways where it doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this solution ---**

```
CREATE TABLE testtel
(
    tel VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

INSERT INTO testtel VALUES
('ID# 12'),
('ID23'),
('45(ID)'),
('MYID'),
('YOUR ID')
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SELECT * 
FROM testtel
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',tel) > 0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
tel
-----------------------------
ID# 12
ID23
45(ID)

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: I tried this, it's not working. Not sure , why? Note: tried with LTRIM and RTRIM.Any other clue?

Comment: What is the data type of your column ?

Comment: The type of the column is Char(15)

Comment: With Char(15) it is working for me. SELECT * 
FROM testtel1
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',CAST(tel AS VARCHAR(MAX))) > 0 Can you please give me what output you are getting ? Which SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the values that contains at least one letter and at least one digit, you can simply check for both, each in it's own patindex:

```
SELECT tel
FROM TableName
WHERE PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',tel) > 0 
AND PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',tel) > 0
```

**Update**
As  Jeroen Mostert wrote in his comment, Like should do the same thing, only better:

```
SELECT tel
FROM TableName
WHERE tel LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%'
AND tel LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: I tried this, it's not working. Not sure , why? Note: tried with LTRIM and RTRIM. Any other clue?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `not working`. Do you get an error?

Comment: No error. However, I'm not getting the desired result.

Comment: [I'm getting exactly the results in your question...](http://rextester.com/PZW98578)